# convert 32 bit long to 4 bytes and back again - CAN Bus

Tags: arduino-uno

So after 2 days attempting this I can't get my head round it.

So I am using CAN bus to transfer accelerometer data and time data (the micros() function if under 71 minutes will output data that can be an unsigned long), however I have to send the data as bytes. I have managed to bit shift a 16-bit int into 2 bytes but I am having trouble extrapolating that method (will add later) to using longs. I am having trouble understanding the union method as I am new to creating my own functions, so, how would you guys accomplish this? As simple as possible please :)

Comment: you subtract the maximum byte 3 can be from the total, and from that subtract the maximum byte 2 can be to get byte 3. byte 4 is just max byte 4 minus number minus max byte 3 +1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve what you want by using [bitshifting](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/structure/bitwise-operators/bitshiftright/) and [bit-wise and](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/structure/bitwise-operators/bitwiseand/) operators.

Here is an example that lets you extract the individual bytes of your `long` variable. I think it should be straigtforward to extend it to variables of different length:

```
void loop() {
  long a=0x12345678, c=0;
  byte b[4];
  Serial.println("Original:");
  Serial.println(a,HEX);
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println("Individual bytes:");
  for (int i=0; i<4; i++)
  {
    b[i]=((a>>(i*8)) & 0xff); //extract the right-most byte of the shifted variable
    Serial.println(b[i],HEX);
    delay(1000);
  }

  for (int i=0; i<4; i++)
  {
    c+=b[i]<<(i*8);
  }
  Serial.println("Reconstructed:");
  Serial.println(c,HEX);
  delay(1000);
}
```

Depending on what byte ordering (big or little endian) is expected, you might need to reorder the bytes before sending or after receiving.

Comment: Very straightforward and easy to understand the principle so thankyou, however under "reconstructed" it only prints 5678?

Comment: Did you copy the code snippet from my answer? Because if I run the code on my nodemcu I get the right answer.

Comment: Yes, i copied and pasted the code, added void setup(); and Serial.begin(9600); to get the code to run on my arduino nano

Comment: by default on an 8 bit AVR, to the right hand side of the equals defaults to int arithmetic which is signed sixteen bit. So i cast the array to a uint32_t in the loop. Unsure of if that is the most efficient way, but it works! Thankyou for your help

Comment: yes right. I didn't think about the arduino controller, when I tried on the nodemcu.

Comment: I'm trying to get this with a long, but no joy

Original:
5294A
Individual bytes:
4A
29
5
0
Reconstructed:
294A

Comment: Anyone have an update to this answer?  It should work on reconstruction (I don't see anything wrong), yet it doesn't.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

The `union` type is similar to a `struct` except that each of the members of the element occupy the same memory. If you define a `struct` so that it has 2 members -- one 4-byte type and one 4-element array of a single byte type, then you can easily refer to the same data as a whole 4-byte element, or byte-wise as you desire.

```
union packed_long {
  long l;
  byte b[4];
};
```

This is the type, so you have to declare the variable to be of that type:

```
packed_long mydata;
```

Now, you have two sub-elements of `mydata`: `l` and `b[]`.

To save your `long` value, write to the `l` part:

```
mydata.l = myaccel.getY();
```

To access each of the 4 bytes:

```
byte1 = mydata.b[0];
byte2 = mydata.b[1];
byte3 = mydata.b[2];
byte4 = mydata.b[3];
```

On the receiving end, you take each of the 4 bytes:

```
mydata.b[0] = canbus.read();
mydata.b[1] = canbus.read();
mydata.b[2] = canbus.read();
mydata.b[4] = canbus.read();
```

As long as you receive the bytes in the same order in which you sent them, you can now access your `long` value in `mydata.l`.

The actual size of different types is dependent on the compiler and architecture, so you may also wish to define your value as a definite-sized variable to ensure you are always working with 32 bits: `int32_t` (signed 32-bit integer) or `uint32_t` (unsigned 32-bit integer).

Answer (score 1):

A way to send a long is to mask off and send the LSB byte (CAN standard), then shift the next one into LSB position, for 4 bytes:

```
uint32_t data;

// Send to CAN bus LSB-first
// This method is destructive; data should be a temp if the
// Arduino is to retain the data after sending it.
for( uint8_t b = 4; b > 0; --b ){
   sendByte(data & 0xFF);  // send curr byte
   data >>= 8;             // shift that byte away
}

// Read from CAN bus
for( uint8_t b = 4; b > 0; --b ){
   data >>= 8;                 // make room for byte
   data |= (readByte() << 8);  // read next higher byte
}
//
```

Comment: OK, so CAN standard is LSB first. As you have knowledge of CAN, from what i can find they send an 8 byte packet, is only one or two of those the data? So for a total of 16 bytes of information, would 8 packets be needed?

Comment: You caught me! That's about everything I know about CAN bus, and that was from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAN_bus). There is a lot of CAN bus documentation online; that article's bibliography is good start.

Comment: 8 byte is the size of the data payload of a standard can-frame. so you need two standard frames to send 16 byte of information. the newer can-fd supports 64 byte data payload per frame.